# Spring batch process runs twice

Tags: spring, spring-batch

My Spring batch process runs twice.

After reading this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589734/spring-batch-processor-called-twice-after-skip), I added  `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` to my application.yml. 
But the job itself did not run.

Then I tried doing some alterations to my job configuration Class. I moved the instance variables to method parameters hoping that would fix the issue. But no luck again.

**Configuration Class**

```
@Configuration
public class CarJobConfiguration {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CarJobConfiguration.class);


    @Value("${com.car-update.thread-count}")
    private int threadCount;

    @Value("${com.car-update.delta-time}")
    private int deltaTime;




    @Bean
    public MongoItemReader<CarMongo> carReader( @Autowired MongoTemplate mongoTemplate, @Value("${com.car-update.chunkSize}") final int chuckSize) {
        MongoItemReader<CarMongo> reader = new MongoItemReader<>();
        reader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
        Map<String, Direction> sortDirection = new HashMap<>();
        sortDirection.put("_id", Direction.DESC);
        reader.setSort(sortDirection);
        reader.setTargetType(CarMongo.class);
        String query = getQuery();
        logger.info("***** Mongo query *****: {}", query);
        reader.setQuery(query);
        reader.setPageSize(chuckSize);
        return reader;
    }


    private String getQuery() {
        // Some logic to get query
    }


    @Bean
    public Job carDeltaJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, @Autowired @Qualifier("carDeltaStep")
             Step carDeltaStep) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("car_delta_extraction")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(carDeltaStep)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step carDeltaStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, 
            @Value("${com.car-update.chunkSize}") final int chuckSize, 
            @Value("${com.car-update.thread-count}") final int threadCount,
            MongoItemReader<CarMongo> mongoItemReader, CarProcessor carProcessor, 
            CarWriter carWriter) {
        System.out.println("STEPSSSS this.chuckSize " + chuckSize +", thread count: " + this.threadCount);
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("car-delta-step")
                .<CarMongo, CarMongo>chunk(chuckSize)
                .reader(mongoItemReader)
                .processor(carProcessor)
                .writer(carWriter)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .throttleLimit(threadCount)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
    //some logic
    }

}
```

**AppConfig.java** *UPDATE*

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing(modular=true)
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextFactory SomeOtherExtractionJob() {
       return new GenericApplicationContextFactory(SomeOtherConfiguration.class);
    }


    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextFactory carDeltaJob() {
       return new GenericApplicationContextFactory(CarJobConfiguration.class);
    }
}
```

**LOGS:**

```
03:04:57.313  INFO 9092 --- [           main] c.w.ProductExtractionApplication         : Starting ProductExtractionApplication on CHMB113786.local with PID 9092 (/Users/andy/Car-Extractionbatch/bin/main started by andy in /Users/andy/Car-Extractionbatch)
03:04:57.318  INFO 9092 --- [           main] c.w.ProductExtractionApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
03:04:57.353  INFO 9092 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@d78795: startup date [Thu Jun 06 03:04:57 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
03:04:57.774  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'catalogExtractionJob' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=appConfig; factoryMethodName=catalogExtractionJob; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/AppConfig.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=catalogExtractionJobConfiguration; factoryMethodName=catalogExtractionJob; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/CatalogExtractionJobConfiguration.class]]
03:04:57.774  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'productCategoryExtractionJob' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=appConfig; factoryMethodName=productCategoryExtractionJob; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/AppConfig.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=categoryExtractionJobConfiguration; factoryMethodName=productCategoryExtractionJob; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/CategoryExtractionJobConfiguration.class]]
03:04:57.775  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'taskExecutor' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=catalogExtractionJobConfiguration; factoryMethodName=taskExecutor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/CatalogExtractionJobConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=categoryExtractionJobConfiguration; factoryMethodName=taskExecutor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/CategoryExtractionJobConfiguration.class]]
03:04:57.775  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dimensionExtractionJob' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=appConfig; factoryMethodName=dimensionExtractionJob; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/AppConfig.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=dimensionExtractionJobConfiguration; factoryMethodName=dimensionExtractionJob; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/DimensionExtractionJobConfiguration.class]]
03:04:57.776  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'taskExecutor' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=categoryExtractionJobConfiguration; factoryMethodName=taskExecutor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/CategoryExtractionJobConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=dimensionExtractionJobConfiguration; factoryMethodName=taskExecutor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/DimensionExtractionJobConfiguration.class]]
03:04:57.776  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'gwpExtractionJob' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=appConfig; factoryMethodName=gwpExtractionJob; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/AppConfig.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=gwpExtractionJobConfiguration; factoryMethodName=gwpExtractionJob; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/GwpExtractionJobConfiguration.class]]
03:04:57.777  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'taskExecutor' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=dimensionExtractionJobConfiguration; factoryMethodName=taskExecutor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/DimensionExtractionJobConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=gwpExtractionJobConfiguration; factoryMethodName=taskExecutor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/GwpExtractionJobConfiguration.class]]
03:04:57.777  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'taskExecutor' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=gwpExtractionJobConfiguration; factoryMethodName=taskExecutor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/GwpExtractionJobConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=carDeltaUpdateJobConfiguration; factoryMethodName=taskExecutor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/CarJobConfiguration.class]]
03:04:57.779  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'productRecommendedExtractionJob' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=appConfig; factoryMethodName=productRecommendedExtractionJob; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/AppConfig.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=productRecommendedExtractionJobConfiguration; factoryMethodName=productRecommendedExtractionJob; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/ProductRecommendedExtractionJobConfiguration.class]]
03:04:57.783  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'skuExtractionJob' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=appConfig; factoryMethodName=skuExtractionJob; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/AppConfig.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=skuExtractionJobConfiguration; factoryMethodName=skuExtractionJob; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/SkuExtractionJobConfiguration.class]]
03:04:57.783  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'taskExecutor' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=carDeltaUpdateJobConfiguration; factoryMethodName=taskExecutor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/CarJobConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=skuExtractionJobConfiguration; factoryMethodName=taskExecutor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/mycar/configuration/SkuExtractionJobConfiguration.class]]
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/Users/andy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.0.5.RELEASE/1bd9feb1d9dac6accd27f5244b6c47cfcb55045c/spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
03:04:58.414  INFO 9092 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
03:04:58.490  INFO 9092 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
03:04:58.500  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: H2
03:04:58.623  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
03:04:58.878  INFO 9092 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[mongo1:27017, mongo2:27017, mongo3:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
03:04:58.879  INFO 9092 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server mongo1:27017 to client view of cluster
03:04:58.924  INFO 9092 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server mongo2:27017 to client view of cluster
03:04:58.927  INFO 9092 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server mongo3:27017 to client view of cluster
03:04:59.051  INFO 9092 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[mongo1:27017, mongo2:27017, mongo3:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
03:04:59.052  INFO 9092 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server mongo1:27017 to client view of cluster
03:04:59.054  INFO 9092 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server mongo2:27017 to client view of cluster
03:04:59.056  INFO 9092 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server mongo3:27017 to client view of cluster
#####from Inside JobCompletionNotificationListener construtor#####
03:04:59.193  INFO 9092 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
03:05:01.912  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:816666}] to mongo2:27017
03:05:01.912  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:816667}] to mongo2:27017
03:05:01.914  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:510177}] to mongo1:27017
03:05:01.914  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:510176}] to mongo1:27017
03:05:01.916  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:6, serverValue:1677186}] to mongo3:27017
03:05:02.206  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=mongo1:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 7]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=288249712, setName='mongodbEnterprise_lowerEnvironment', canonicalAddress=mongo1:27017, hosts=[mongo2:27017, mongo3:27017, mongo1:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='mongo1:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=7fffffff0000000000000127, setVersion=2, lastWriteDate=Thu Jun 06 03:05:05 IST 2019, lastUpdateTimeNanos=368580308198796}
03:05:02.207  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=mongo3:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 7]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=290187882, setName='mongodbEnterprise_lowerEnvironment', canonicalAddress=mongo3:27017, hosts=[mongo2:27017, mongo3:27017, mongo1:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='mongo1:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=2, lastWriteDate=Thu Jun 06 03:05:05 IST 2019, lastUpdateTimeNanos=368580309720591}
03:05:02.207  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=mongo2:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 7]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=288378005, setName='mongodbEnterprise_lowerEnvironment', canonicalAddress=mongo2:27017, hosts=[mongo2:27017, mongo3:27017, mongo1:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='mongo1:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=2, lastWriteDate=Thu Jun 06 03:05:05 IST 2019, lastUpdateTimeNanos=368580309928421}
03:05:02.206  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=mongo1:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 7]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=286870787, setName='mongodbEnterprise_lowerEnvironment', canonicalAddress=mongo1:27017, hosts=[mongo2:27017, mongo3:27017, mongo1:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='mongo1:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=7fffffff0000000000000127, setVersion=2, lastWriteDate=Thu Jun 06 03:05:05 IST 2019, lastUpdateTimeNanos=368580308253613}
03:05:02.209  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Discovered cluster type of REPLICA_SET
03:05:02.210  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Setting max election id to 7fffffff0000000000000127 from replica set primary mongo1:27017
03:05:02.210  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Discovered cluster type of REPLICA_SET
03:05:02.210  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Setting max set version to 2 from replica set primary mongo1:27017
03:05:02.211  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Setting max election id to 7fffffff0000000000000127 from replica set primary mongo1:27017
03:05:02.211  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Discovered replica set primary mongo1:27017
03:05:02.212  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Setting max set version to 2 from replica set primary mongo1:27017
03:05:02.213  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Discovered replica set primary mongo1:27017
03:05:02.216  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:1677187}] to mongo3:27017
03:05:02.218  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=mongo2:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 7]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=301879122, setName='mongodbEnterprise_lowerEnvironment', canonicalAddress=mongo2:27017, hosts=[mongo2:27017, mongo3:27017, mongo1:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='mongo1:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=2, lastWriteDate=Thu Jun 06 03:05:05 IST 2019, lastUpdateTimeNanos=368580320523441}
03:05:02.487  INFO 9092 --- [reens.com:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=mongo3:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 7]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=269161222, setName='mongodbEnterprise_lowerEnvironment', canonicalAddress=mongo3:27017, hosts=[mongo2:27017, mongo3:27017, mongo1:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='mongo1:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=2, lastWriteDate=Thu Jun 06 03:05:06 IST 2019, lastUpdateTimeNanos=368580589179359}
03:05:04.645  INFO 9092 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:510178}] to mongo1:27017
03:09:05.799  WARN 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.s.b.FaultTolerantStepBuilder     : Asynchronous TaskExecutor detected with ItemStream reader.  This is probably an error, and may lead to incorrect restart data being stored.
***** Mongo query *****: {'dttm' : { $gte: ISODate('2019-06-06T02:39:06.434209Z')}}
STEPSSSS this.chuckSize 1000, thread count: 10
03:09:06.575  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql]
03:09:06.614  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql] in 38 ms.
03:09:06.976  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
03:09:06.980  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'batchDataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
03:09:06.981  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'mariaDB' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
03:09:06.986  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'mariaDB': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=mariaDB,type=HikariDataSource]
03:09:06.988  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'batchDataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=batchDataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
03:09:06.992  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase -2147482648
03:09:06.995  INFO 9092 --- [           main] ory$ResourceAnnotationApplicationContext : Refreshing ResourceAnnotationApplicationContext:com.mycar.configuration.CarJobConfiguration
***** Mongo query *****: {'dttm' : { $gte: ISODate('2019-06-06T02:39:07.00335Z')}}
STEPSSSS this.chuckSize 1000, thread count: 10
03:09:07.095  INFO 9092 --- [           main] c.w.ProductExtractionApplication         : Started CarExtractionApplication in 250.186 seconds (JVM running for 251.358)
03:09:07.097  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: [--spring.output.ansi.enabled=always]
03:09:07.141  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=car_delta_extraction]] launched with the following parameters: [{-spring.output.ansi.enabled=always, run.id=1}]
03:09:07.159  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [car-delta-step]
********** Processor **********
********** Processor **********
03:09:26.017  INFO 9092 --- [           main] c.w.l.JobCompletionNotificationListener  : !!! JOB FINISHED! Time to verify the results  : 18 seconds
03:09:26.019  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=car_delta_extraction]] completed with the following parameters: [{-spring.output.ansi.enabled=always, run.id=1}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
03:09:26.066  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=car_delta_extraction]] launched with the following parameters: [{-spring.output.ansi.enabled=always, run.id=2}]
03:09:26.073  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [car-delta-step]
********** Processor **********
********** Processor **********
03:09:31.753  INFO 9092 --- [           main] c.w.l.JobCompletionNotificationListener  : !!! JOB FINISHED! Time to verify the results  : 5 seconds
03:09:31.755  INFO 9092 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=car_delta_extraction]] completed with the following parameters: [{-spring.output.ansi.enabled=always, run.id=2}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
03:09:31.757  INFO 9092 --- [       Thread-1] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@d78795: startup date [Thu Jun 06 03:04:57 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
03:09:31.759  INFO 9092 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase -2147482648
03:09:31.760  INFO 9092 --- [       Thread-1] ory$ResourceAnnotationApplicationContext : Closing ResourceAnnotationApplicationContext:com.mycar.configuration.CarJobConfiguration
03:09:31.766  INFO 9092 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
03:09:31.767  INFO 9092 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
03:09:32.042  INFO 9092 --- [       Thread-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:7, serverValue:510178}] to mongo1:27017 because the pool has been closed.
03:09:32.043  INFO 9092 --- [       Thread-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
03:09:32.048  INFO 9092 --- [       Thread-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

From the Logs, you can notice that

- *********** Processor *********** is printed twice.(Processor is printed twice each time as there are 2 records only)
- Mongo Query and the **chunck size and threadcount** are printed twice.
- **!!! JOB FINISHED! Time to verify the results  :** __ is printed twice

Any suggestion would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Have you configured `CarJobConfiguration` in a child `ApplicationContext`?

Comment: @PhilipWrage: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I have configured. I have updated the post with AppConfig.java. 
The issue got fixed after I had the **same *name*  carDeltaJob()** in both **AppConfig.java** and **CarJobConfiguration.java**
I am not able to figure out the actual reason although it is working fine now. Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

I had this happen recently for a `Job` created in the method `runScenario()`. In my Spring Boot App, I had this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SimulationBatchServiceApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

  @Autowired
  private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

  @Autowired
  private Job job;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SimulationBatchServiceApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
      JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addString("runScenario", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .toJobParameters();
      jobLauncher.run(job, params);
  }
}
```

`runScenario()` was also marked with `@Bean`. Spring therefore picked it up twice -- once to `@Autowire` the `job` field, once because I specified `"runScenario"` in `JobParameters`. Removing `"runScenario"` from the `JobParameters` object did the trick.

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
}
```

If I required a more dynamic case, I believe I could have removed `@Bean` and the `job` field, then specified `"runScenario"` in `JobParameters`. That way no autowiring would've occurred, but the job would've been found anyway by looking for the method name.

Perhaps this isn't your issue, but hopefully it provides a clue (or helps a future reader!)